# How to get all svn revision details between 2 dates

Tags: svn

How can I get the all svn revision commit detail between 2 date (ex;- 16 Feb to 17 Feb).. and How can I make a script for automation .

Comment: How this question related to git-svn?

Answer (score 5):

try:

`svn log -v -r {2014-02-16}:{2014-02-17}`

But note that the first date will also pick the last commit before this date.

To automate the answer you can use output of command 
`date +%F` for today and you can perform date calculation using calculation on the elapsed seconds from reference time that you get with `date +%S`.
Use `date --date @<integer> +%F` to convert back to YYYY-MM-DD format.

in bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=`date +%s`
yesterday=$(( now - 24*3600 ))
d1=`date --date @$yesterday +%F`
d2=`date +%F`
svn log -v -r {$d1}:{$d2}
```

--
NH

Comment: I tried to run below script.. but am unable to make it running condition.   Could you pls guide some more hints...Thanks You..

Comment: I've tested and it run just as it is.
Check that you give executable permission to that script file.
1- Copy that code to file /tmp/svn_log_from_yesterday.sh
2- run `chmod +x /tmp/svn_log_from_yesterday.sh`
3- invoke like this from your working dir or subdir:
`/tmp/svn_log_from_yesterday.sh`. This doesn't work ?

Comment: You can use cron to make it run on a daily basis and redirect output to file.

Answer (score 1):

Extraction from `svn help log`

```
Valid options:   -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                ...
                                '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
```

For possible formats of date read SVN Book, Chapter 3 "Advanced Topics", "Revision Specifiers" section, ["Revision Dates" topic](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) and pay attention to note "Is Subversion a Day Early?"

Comment: thanks, am able to get it.. How can I make automated this task.. so everyday it should generate the commit list from previous date to till today date